# How can I display legend in two columns in pie chart

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I want to display legend in two columns in the pie chart. My JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cp73s/2185/

```
itemStyle: {            
                 width:200,
                 font: 'Helvetica Neue'
              },
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    legend: {
        borderRadius: 0,
        borderColor: 'silver',
        enabled: true,
        margin: 30,
        itemMarginTop: 2,
        itemMarginBottom: 2,
        width:200,
        itemWidth:100,
        itemStyle: {
          width:100
        }   
    }
```

[fiddle link :)](http://jsfiddle.net/Cp73s/2186/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  function renderElements() {
      if (this.legend) {
       this.legend.destroy();
      }
      //distance between 2 elements
      let itemDistance = this.legend.options.itemDistance;
      //the biggest element
      let maxItemWidth = this.legend.maxItemWidth;
      //make the width of the legend in the size of 2 largest elements + 
      //distance  
      let nextLegendWidth = (maxItemWidth * 2) + itemDistance;
      //container width
      let boxWidth = this.plotBox.width;
      //if the length of the 2 largest elements + the distance between them 
      //is less than the width of           container, we make 1 row, else 
      //set legend width 2 max elements + distance between
    if (boxWidth < nextLegendWidth) {
     this.legend.options.width = maxItemWidth;
    } else {
     this.legend.options.width = nextLegendWidth;
  }

  this.render()   
}

chart: {
    events: {
      load: renderElements,
      redraw: renderElements
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jecrovb7/38/

Comment: Could you please explain your answer a bit?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a bunch of things in order to make it look as you expecting.
First you need to change the `layout` parameter to `'horizontal'`, enable the `floating`, setting fixed `width` of legend for example to `300` and finally - position it by `x, y` parameters. Here is the code and example:

```
  legend: {
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    layout: 'horizontal',
    floating: true,
    useHTML: true,
    symbolWidth: 0,
    width: 300,
    y: 80,
    itemMarginTop: 5,
    itemMarginBottom: 5,
    itemStyle: {
      width: 200,
      font: 'Helvetica Neue'
    },
  }
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/9pnru4s7/